# Discord bot disconnects for 0 reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

**Hello.**

I'm hosting a Discord bot and it **disconnects** after a few hours for no reason!

This is a bot that pings the `Apex Legends` game servers every minute to see the status of the servers and displays the number of server pings.
I already have 2 other bots I created and they won't disconnect.
I saw with the developer of the bot on the official Apex Legends server because an admin gave it to me but he also doesn't understand why the bot is disconnecting.
The bot on their servers has no problem.
I don't get any logs, just the server shows offline.
I changed node.js version but nothing works, it keeps disconnecting.

**If anyone has an idea, I'm a taker.**

- Server Image
  [image: Server Image]
- Server Discord

  [image: Server Discord]

I tried to update the nodejs but nothing happened.

Comment: Maybe they are crashing. Try to save the log and see if there is an error causing this.

Answer (score 0):

suggest you ensure you have unhandled exception, unhandled rejection, etc. calls covered in your bot, so that it doesn't crash, and gracefully exits.  You can also use something like pm2, which will restart on crash, so you can continue, and then diagnose the crashes without downtime.

Comment: I'm not strong at all in this area of programming, I need more help than that, I've watched videos on YouTube but I don't understand and I can't.
Couldn't it be simpler?

When I start the server the bot sends me 2 warns:

"npm WARN deprecated @discordjs/builders@0.16.0: no longer supported"

&

DeprecationWarning: MessageEmbed#addField is deprecated and will be removed in the next major update. Use MessageEmbed#addFields instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)

Comment: These are because you're using Discord.js version <14.  If you upgrade those, you'll get rid of the warnings...but that doesn't have anything to do with your original question.

Comment: How to solve this problem of disconnection easily suddenly? It is not supposed to be disconnected! I don't understand

Comment: adding in resilience, you can use something like pm2 as a restart engine.  But you should be solving the errors that causes the crashes in the first place, and debug the reasons for those.

Comment: Ok, I have news of this problem!
I tried locally and managed to get logs...
Do you see a problem in all of this?

File logs : [Logs.txt](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1010305161979244686/1063466513979412621/Logs.txt)

Comment: are you running this from a home PC?  Your error is about your connection being reset.  I am guessing since this is windows, it's your PC or laptop.  It could go to sleep, etc...your internet might have sleep time at night when you don't have access etc.  You need a permanent stable network (think cloud hosted VPS) to run a bot...